# How to manage the width in listView.Builder() of Text?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to my text to elippsis if it's size is greater than the width of the container but actually it's taking the space and giving the error of render flex.[image]
And can someone give me a suggestion how can I improve my code I want a list view where a list is slidable .
And also how to dynamically I can set width because i needed a fixed header so that it does not move when I scroll the it should remains.
This is my code

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, prefer_const_constructors, unused_field, unused_element, unused_import
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:cryptocornars/common/widget/common_widget.dart';
import 'package:cryptocornars/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:cryptocornars/features/market/screen/view_model/coins_view_model.dart';
import 'package:cryptocornars/model/market/coins_model.dart';
import 'package:cryptocornars/provider/filter_provider.dart';
import 'package:cryptocornars/provider/token_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class CoinsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CoinsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CoinsPage> createState() => _CoinsPageState();
}

class _CoinsPageState extends State<CoinsPage> {
  final List _peopleData = List.generate(100, (index) {
    return {"name": "Person #$index", "age": Random().nextInt(90) + 10};
  });
  late CoinsViewModel viewModel = CoinsViewModel();
  List<Coins>? item;

  Widget _itemsBuild(index, width, margin) {
    final items = item![index];
    final data = items.data![index];

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: (width / 4) + 15,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 0, top: 5, bottom: 0),
            child: Text(
              "#$index",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: width + 20,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1, top: 5, bottom: 0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Image.network(
                    data.coinLogo!,
                    width: 25,
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          data.coinName!,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "324.44Bn",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: width,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 5, bottom: 0),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  data.currentPrice.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: width - 15,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 5, bottom: 0),
              child: Text(
                data.priceChange24hPercentage!.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    viewModel.loadCoinData("marketCap", "desc", "100", "1");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var token = Provider.of<AccessToken>(context, listen: false).token;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double columnWidth = screenWidth / 5;
    double mar = (columnWidth / 5) + 1;
    var margin = EdgeInsets.all(mar);
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<CoinsViewModel>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => viewModel,
        child: Consumer<CoinsViewModel>(
          builder: (context, viewModel, _) {
            debugPrint("length ${viewModel.coinsModel.length}");
            item = viewModel.coinsModel;

            return Scaffold(
              body: Column(children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 10, bottom: 0, left: 10, right: 10),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: columnWidth / 4,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 6, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                        child: Text(
                          '#',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: columnWidth + 10,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: mar + 10, top: 0, right: mar, bottom: 0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Market Cap',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: columnWidth + 10,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: mar + 2, top: 0, right: mar, bottom: 0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Price(USD)',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        // width: columnWidth,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: mar + 10, top: 0, right: mar, bottom: 0),
                        child: Text(
                          '24h%',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: viewModel.getCoinDataResponse.isLoading &&
                          viewModel.coinsModel.isEmpty
                      ? const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        )
                      : viewModel.getCoinDataResponse.isError
                          ? Center(
                              child: emptyWidget(
                                  viewModel.getCoinDataResponse.message ??
                                      someThingWentWrong,
                                  '',
                                  'assets/images/blank_report.png'),
                            )
                          : ListView.builder(
                              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: viewModel.coinsModel.length,
                              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                                return Slidable(
                                  endActionPane: ActionPane(
                                    motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                                    children: [
                                      SlidableAction(
                                        onPressed: (ctx) {
                                          doNothing(ctx, "Alerts");
                                        },
                                        backgroundColor: Color(0xff1C2B5E),
                                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        icon: Icons.notifications,
                                        label: 'Alerts',
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                            topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8)),
                                      ),
                                      SlidableAction(
                                        onPressed: (ctx) {
                                          doNothing(ctx, "Watchlist");
                                        },
                                        backgroundColor:
                                            const Color(0xFF0096FF),
                                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        icon: Icons.star,
                                        label: 'Watchlist',
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                            topRight: Radius.circular(8),
                                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(8)),
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                        spacing: 5,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  child: _itemsBuild(index, columnWidth, mar),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                )
              ]),
            );
          },
        ));
  }

  void doNothing(BuildContext context, String text) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("Alert Dialog Box"),
        content: Text("You have raised a Alert Dialog Box, $text "),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black45,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
              child: const Text(
                "okay",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try wrap the Text widget with the FittedBox widget. And set the fit value to BoxFit.scaldown.

Comment: I tried using that but nothing changed

Answer (score 3):

*You can use `Expanded and flex`*

```
Row(
childern:[
Expanded(flex:1, child: Container(height:20, color:Colors.red),  
Expanded(flex:1, child: Container(height:20, color:Colors.green),
Expanded(flex:1, child: Container(height:20, color:Colors.blue),    
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!
on your Widget build(BuildContext context) and before retrurn :

```
final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

final screenHeight = mediaQuery.size.height -
        AppBar().preferredSize.height -
        mediaQuery.padding.top;
final screenWidth = mediaQuery.size.width;
```

on list view builder :

```
Container(
      width: screenWidth,
      child: Row(
          children: [
                Expanded(
                   flex: 1,
                   child: child),
                Expanded(
                   flex: 1,
                   child: child),
                Expanded(
                   flex: 1,
                   child: child),
                Expanded(
                   flex: 1,
                   child: child),
                Expanded(
                   flex: 1,
                   child: child),
                Expanded(
                   flex: 1,
                   child: child),
      ]),)
```